# Error during XML parsing

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to do XML parsing and get the data for `file_name` and `file_path` but running into below error ,can anyone help to figure out why and how to resolve it?

INPUT XML:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <contents>
    <build>
      <name>modem</name>
      <role>modem</role>
      <chipset>mms1234</chipset> 
    </build>
    <build>
      <name>boot</name>
      <role>boot</role>
      <chipset>ms1234</chipset>
      <device_programmer minimized="true">
        <file_name>prog_emmc_house_4567_ddr.elf</file_name>
        <file_path>images/comPkg/Msm4567Pkg/Bin64/</file_path>
      </device_programmer>
      <flash_programmer minimized="true">
      </flash_programmer>
    </build>
    </contents>
```

CODE:-

```
contents_xml_file = r"device_programmer.xml"
print contents_xml_file
tree = ET.parse(contents_xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()
device_programmer = root.find("device_programmer")

file_name = device_programmer.get('file_name')
print file_name
file_path = device_programmer.get('file_path')
print file_path
```

ERROR:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 37, in <module>
    file_name = device_programmer.get('file_name')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Element.findall() finds only elements with a tag which are direct children of the current element. Element.find() finds the first child with a particular tag, and Element.text accesses the element’s text content. Element.get() accesses the element’s attributes:

This is why

```
device_programmer = root.find("device_programmer")
```

returned `None` since there is no `device_programmer` element directly under the `root`.

You should probably be using XPath syntax:

```
device_programmer = root.find("//device_programmer")
```

Comment: what is `[2]` in build[2]

Comment: Second `build` tag under root.

Comment: above xml is just an example,it doesnt have to be in 2nd position,it can be anywhere in the xml,need more generic solution

Comment: I changed it to examine all `device_programmer` nodes regardless of where they occur.

Comment: did it work for you,it throws an error `raise SyntaxError("cannot use absolute path on element")
SyntaxError: cannot use absolute path on element`

Comment: Just add a `.` at the beginning : `root.find(".//device_programmer")` ...

Comment: I added that but I get incorrect output..output is `None` for both `file_name` and  `file_path`

Answer (score 0):

Since `device_programmer` is not direct child of the root element, you need to add `.//` at the beginning. The `.` indicates that the XPath is relative to the context element (the root element in this case), and `//` is abbreviated syntax for `descendant-or-self` axis :

```
device_programmer = root.find(".//device_programmer")
```

Instead of attributes, `file_name` and `file_path` are direct child of `device_programmer`, so you need to use `find('element_name')` to get them :

```
file_name = device_programmer.find('file_name')
print file_name.text
file_path = device_programmer.find('file_path')
print file_path.text
```